# Problem with showing buttons after I hide them

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making an idle game with my friend. We want to hide the buttons for the upgrades until you have bought the last tier. In this example, you need 10 gold for the buttons to show up. We successfully hide them, but can't show them afterward. What am I doing wrong?

Have tried several different ways of showing and hiding, finally figured out that the if the test in the jquery blocks are not triggering

```js
var data = {
    gold: 0,
    goldPerClick: 1,
    goldPerClickCost: 10,
    goldPerSec: 0,
    rentaPaulCost: 100,
    rentaPaulLevel: 0,
    goldGenTimer: 10000,
    hjulLasterLevel: 0,
    hjulLasterCost: 500,
    tanksCost: 1000,
    tanksLevel: 0,
    goldPerClickButton: 10,
}
  
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#paulUpgrade").hide();
  $("#hjulLaster").hide();
  $("#tanks").hide();

  $("#perClickUpgrade").click(function(){
    if (data.gold >= 10) {
        $("#paulUpgrade").show();
    }
  });

  $("#paulUpgrade").click(function(){
    $("#hjulLaster").show();
  });
    
  $("#hjulLaster").click(function(){
    $("#tanks").show();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <p id="goldMined">0 Gold Mined </p>
  <p id="goldPerSec">0 Gold per Second</p>
  <button class="btn" onclick="mineGold()">Mine Gold</button>
  <br>
  <button class="btn" onclick="buyGoldPerClick()" id="perClickUpgrade"> Pickaxe (Currently Level 1) Cost: 10 Gold</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="rentaPaul()" id ="paulUpgrade"> Rent a Paul (Currently Level 0) Cost 100 Gold</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="hjulLaster()" id ="hjulLaster"> HjulLaster Upgrade for Paul (Currently Level 0) Cost 500 Gold</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="tanks()" id ="tanks"> Tanks upgrade for paul (Currently level 0) cost 1000 Gold </button>
</div>
```

The new buttons should show up if the user has the required amount of gold but nothing happens, no errors in chromes console either

Answer (score 0):

the initial value of `data.gold` is 0 .

in the code that you provided, I do not see where you increment it to get to 10.

the  condition `(data.gold >= 10)` will always be false, so the block that follows will never be executed .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample example

If `gold >= 10` and you click on `Pickaxe` next upgrade button will show up

```js
var data = {
    gold: 0,
    goldPerClick: 10
}
  
function mineGold(){
    data.gold += data.goldPerClick;
    $("#goldMined").html(data.gold);
}
  
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#paulUpgrade").hide();

  $("#perClickUpgrade").click(function(){
    if (data.gold >= 10) {
        $("#paulUpgrade").show();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <p><span id="goldMined">0</span> Gold Mined </p>
  <button class="btn" onclick="mineGold()">Mine Gold</button>
  <br>
  <button class="btn" id="perClickUpgrade"> Pickaxe (Currently Level 1) Cost: 10 Gold</button>
  <button class="btn"id ="paulUpgrade"> Rent a Paul (Currently Level 0) Cost 100 Gold</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```js
var firstButton = document.querySelector('button');
firstButton.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    var secondButton = document.getElementById('other');
    secondButton.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
<button id="other" class="hidden">Now You Can See Me</button>
```